# Game review website: Review schema with missing info or Article schema?

Tags: seo, wordpress, schema.org, website-review

I run a board game review website. I'm using the WP SSO plugin with the Review schema add on. Unfortunately the plugin is having some issues with picking up some data from my review content.

My question is: is it better to use the Review schema type with missing information, or to fall back to the Article schema type so that the entire post is valid? I'm concerned I might be getting dinged for incomplete or invalid data.

Thoughts?